# Unable to retrieve data from SQLite

Tags: java, android, eclipse, sqlite

Please have a look at the following code

**DatabaseHandler.java**

The code used to retrieve data

```
public List<String> getAllBranches() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String selectQuery = "select city from BranchNetwork";

        Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        List <String>branches = new ArrayList<String>();

        if(cursor.isFirst())
        {
            do
            {

            }
            while(cursor.moveToNext());

            Toast.makeText(context, "Data Retrieved: "+branches.get(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        return branches;
    }
```

The code used to insert data

```
public String insertData(String city, String streetAddress,String phoneNumber1, String phoneNumber2, String email) 
    {
        String insertQuery = "insert into BranchNetwork ('city','streetAddress','phoneNumber1','phoneNumber2','email') values('"+city+"','"+streetAddress+"','"+phoneNumber1+"','"+phoneNumber2+"','"+email+"');";




        try
        {  
            database.execSQL(insertQuery);


            return "Data Successfully Inserted";

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Exception: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return "Data Insertion Failed";
        }

    }
```

**Form.java**

The first Activity. Here I retrieve the data and insert the data. Following is how I retrieve the data

```
public class Form extends Activity {
    private List<String>branches = new ArrayList<String>();
        private DatabaseConnector databaseConnector;
    String[]arr;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_form);

            databaseConnector = DatabaseHandler.getInstance(this);
            databaseConnector.createConnection();

            branches = databaseConnector.getAllBranches();

             arr = branches.toArray(new String[branches.size()]);
    }
}
```

But, I never get anything! In DatabaseHandler.java, I have made a `Toast` where it should generate a message when the code is retrieved. But it is not generating anything! I am loading the data into a `ListView` but it is also empty! Why is this? Please help!

PS:
Following is the DatabaseConnector.java, the insert face for DatabaseHandler

```
package com.example.esoftcallmanager;

import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;

public interface DatabaseConnector 
{
    public void createConnection();
    public void closeConnection();
    public String getPhoneNumber();
    public String insertData(String city, String streetAddress, String phoneNumber1, String phoneNumber2, String email);
    public List<String>getAllBranches();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forget to add the data in your array of list.
Try out as below:

> ```
>   String selectQuery = "select city from BranchNetwork";
>     Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
>     List <String> branches = new ArrayList<String>();
>     String str=null;
>     cursor.moveToFirst();
>         do
>        {
>          str= m_cursor.getString(m_cursor.getColumnIndex("city"));
>           branches.add(str);
>        }
>         while(cursor.moveToNext());
>         Toast.makeText(context, "Data Retrieved: "+branches.get(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>     }
>         return branches;
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. what is m_cursor ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that your database has data already, try to change `if(cursor.isFirst())` to `if(cursor.moveToFirst())`

Answer (score 1):

try cursor.moveToFirst() Condition

```
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {

        }
        while(cursor.moveToNext());

        Toast.makeText(context, "Data Retrieved: "+branches.get(1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're not really doing anything with the data.

First of all you have to move the cursor's position to first yourself: cursor.moveToFirst() 
After that you can start a while loop as you're trying to do.

Secondly, you never actually put the data in your List branches, you'll have to place the data from the cursor in there first.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this works.

```
public List<String> getAllBranches() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            String selectQuery = "select city from BranchNetwork";
            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            List <String>branches = new ArrayList<String>();

             if(cursor != null){
              cursor.moveToFirst();

               Toast.makeText(context, "Data Retrieved: ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

              do
                {

                }
                while(cursor.moveToNext());



             }



                return branches;
        }
```